# jQuery - Address plugin problem

Tags: jquery-plugins, url-rewriting

I've come across a problem which i cant seem to figure out, i use the jQuery address plugin to store history and enable deep linking, and a typical url after a click would look like this:

```
http://mysite.com/#!/page
```

Problem here is i need rid of the last `/` so i need it to look like this:

```
http://mysite.com/#!page
```

I'm using plugin version 1.2 - the latest is 1.4. When i use 1.4 my hashbang `#!` disappears.. 
Anyone know why? even so, the updated version produces the same problem.

Reasons to fix this are i use 301 redirects to 'Pretty URL's' if an `?_escaped_fragment_=` is requested. So this:

```
http://mysite.com/data/#!page1
```

would become:

```
http://mysite.com/data/page1
```

currently it does this: `mysite.com/data//page1`

here is the .htaccess rewrite:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  # Rewrite current-style URLs of the form 'index.php?url=x'.
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

and here is some relevant PHP i use on page load:

```
if ($fragment = $_GET['_escaped_fragment_']) {
    // OPTION 1: if Google is reqesting an '_escaped_fragment_=' page, then redirect to a clean URL
    header("Location: $base/$fragment", 1, 301);
    exit;
}
```

Any help on how to make this situation better is appreciated.. I don't want 'use the HTML5 History API' as ive explored this option already.

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer and mark it as accepted -- in this case it will be more useful for those in similar situations as right now your question does not looks attractive as it has 0 answers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line of code can help!

```
$.address.strict(false);
```